# Finding the limit in terms of a without using L'Hospitals

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find $\;\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{1-\cos(ax)}{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}}\;$ in terms of a without using L'Hospitals Rule.

I first graphed the function and noticed that that limit tends to go towards $-a^2$

I also tried this approach:
$\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{1-\cos(ax)}{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{2 \cdot \frac{1-\cos(ax)}{2}}{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{2\sin^2(\frac{ax}{2})}{1 - \sqrt{1+x^2}} $

However, I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried rationalizing the denominator but it only makes it more tangled.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $-a^2$. Will edit it.

Comment: Try multiplying above and below by $1+\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: It would have been helpful to show the "more tangled" that made you want to avoid rationalizing the denominator, since that's what the answer and cooper hat both (correctly) suggest to do.

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the correct path. I didn't see how to proceed until @Wang YeFei gave additional guidance.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Multiply both numerator and denominator of the expression by $1+\sqrt{1+x^2}$ and your expression will have the factor $-\dfrac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2}$. Then use the identity $1-\cos(ax) = 2\sin^2\left(\frac{ax}{2}\right)$ and the known fact about limit: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ to obtain the desire result.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to @Wang YeFei for the hint.

$\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{1-\cos(ax)}{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{2 \cdot \frac{1-\cos(ax)}{2}}{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{2\sin^2(\frac{ax}{2})}{1 - \sqrt{1+x^2}} $

Then we proceed to multiply the numerator and denominator by $1 - \sqrt{1+x^2}$:

$\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{2\sin^2(\frac{ax}{2})}{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}} \cdot \dfrac{1 - \sqrt{1+x^2}}{1 - \sqrt{1+x^2}} = \lim_\limits{x \to 0} -\dfrac{[2\sin^2(\frac{ax}{2})][1 - \sqrt{1+x^2}]}{x^2}$

Then, to be able to use the fact that $\lim_ \limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$, we multiply the numerator and denominator by $\dfrac{a^2}{4}$:

$\lim_\limits{x \to 0} -\dfrac{[2\sin^2(\frac{ax}{2})][1 - \sqrt{1+x^2}]}{x^2} \cdot \dfrac{\frac{a^2}{4}}{\frac{a^2}{4}} = \lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{[\sin^2(\frac{ax}{2})][-\frac{1}{2}a^2][1 - \sqrt{1+x^2}]}{\dfrac{a^2x^2}{4}}$

$=\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin^2(\frac{ax}{2})}{\dfrac{a^2x^2}{4}} \cdot \lim_\limits{x \to 0} \hspace{0.2cm} (-\frac{1}{2}a^2)(1 - \sqrt{1+x^2})$
$= \left( \lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(\frac{ax}{2})}{\dfrac{ax}{2}}\right)^2 \cdot \lim_\limits{x \to 0} \hspace{0.2cm} (-\frac{1}{2}a^2)(1 - \sqrt{1+x^2})$

$= \lim_\limits{x \to 0} \hspace{0.2cm} (-\frac{1}{2}a^2)(1 - \sqrt{1+x^2})=-a^2$